Lower bound on complexity of eigenvector computation
Is there anything known about the lower bound on the complexity of computing the smallest eigenvalue eigenvector (upto some error $\epsilon$).
Its straightforward that a lower bound should be either $n^{2}$ (from entries in the matrix) or $n\log(b)$ (from number of bits in the eigenvector), but that feels like it would be loose and there is a gap to existing algorithms.

Not an answer, but somewhat related https://mathoverflow.net/q/62904/31729.

Yeah, but that is an upper bound on the complexity which tends to be easier to create
